# How to bin a column and keep null values in a separate group

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a column with continuous variable and wanted to bin it for plotting. However, this column also contains null values.

I used the following code to bin it:

```py
def a(b):
  if b<= 20: return "<= 20"
  elif b<= 40: return "20 < <= 40"
  elif b<= 45: return "40 < <= 45"
  else: return "> 45"
audf = udf(a, StringType())
data= data.withColumn("a_bucket", audf("b"))
```

I am running on Python 3 and throw me the following error:

```py
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I look up some documentations saying Python 3 won't allow comparison between numbers with null value. But is there a way for me to throw those null values into a separate group so I won't throw away data. They are not bad data.

Thanks.

Comment: put `if b is None: return "OTHER"` at the top of your `udf`, but  you can easily do this without a `udf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a `udf`. Here is one way to rewrite your code, and have a special bucket for `null` values:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

def a(b):
    return when(b.isNull(), "Other")\
        .when(b <= 20, "<= 20")\
        .when(b <= 40, "20 < <= 40")\
        .when(b <= 45, "40 < <= 45")\
        .otherwise("> 45")

data = data.withColumn("a_bucket", a(col("b")))
```

---

However, a more general solution would allow you to pass in a list of buckets and dynamically return the bin output (untested):

```
from functools import reduce

def aNew(b, buckets):
    """assumes buckets are sorted"""
    if not buckets:
        raise ValueError("buckets can not be empty")
    return reduce(
        lambda w, i: w.when(
            b.between(buckets[i-1], buckets[i]), 
            "{low} < <= {high}".format(low=buckets[i-1], high=buckets[i]))
        ),
        range(1, len(buckets)),
        when(
            b.isNull(), 
            "Other"
        ).when(
            b <= buckets[0], 
            "<= {first}".format(first=buckets[0])
        )
    ).otherwise("> {last}".format(last=buckets[-1]))

data = data.withColumn("a_bucket", aNew(col("b"), buckets=[20, 40, 45]))
```